# Failing to install pyleargist

Tags: python, fftw

I am trying to install [Pyleargist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyleargist/2.0.5) in `MacOS 10.10` for global image descriptors to identify objects in an image. `Pyleargist` needs [libfftw3](http://www.fftw.org/), I installed it using `fink` as can be seen here: [image: Fink List screenshot].

When I try to install `pyleargist`, it says `ld: library not found for -lfftw3f`. How do I fix it? Is there any other library for Global image descriptors?

Answer (score 0):

I passed the library and header paths to setup.py during build phase.

```
python setup.py build_ext -I/opt/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/
```

This was followed with

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Hope this works out.

Edit : I should have mentioned that I installed fftw3 using homebrew.